# Can i get a python dictionary that contains lists in the values to dump to JSON with the list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a python dictionary, of which some values are lists. When I iterate through the dict and print the value it prints only 1 value of the list - and the same when i use json.dump()

Is there a way I can get a JSON file that contains these lists?

my dict:

```
{
 'key1': 'value1',
 'key2': ['value2.1,' 'value2.2', 'value2.3']
 }
```

code:

```
    with open('/path/to/mydict_JSON.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(mydict, outfile)
```

output JSON:

```
    {'key1': 'value1','key2': 'value2.1'}
```

Comment: Nope, can not reproduce (using `json.dumps`, but anyway). Are you 100% positively sure that your dict looks like this? Maybe you add the list values in a loop, overwriting the previous values each time?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post a complete code sample (one that we can copy-and-paste and run locally) that reproduces the problem.